# How to configure a virtual environment that doesn't require sudo?

Tags: python, pip, easy-install

In my Ubuntu 12.04 machine, the installation of pip requirements is asking me for sudo permission every time it attempts to install. How would I override this, as this is terrible for my working environment to install things globally instead of inside the venv?

Note: I did not setup the venv using sudo.

Comment: Your virtual environment has a private `bin/pip`; use that instead.

Comment: @MartijnPieters it's the one being used when I which pip, I get my venv path/bin.

Comment: Did you create the virtual env with any other user at all? Could you include the `ls -la` of `bin/` and `lib/python*/site-packages`?

Comment: What is the command you are using _exactly_ to install the requirements file?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid pip install -r requirements.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @MartijnPieters, I found a workaround:

Running

```
~/.virtualenvs/myapp/bin/pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Instead of just

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you activated your virtual environment? Run:

```
. bin/activate
```

in your shell. Then the local `pip` installation will take over the system one.

Comment: Yup. It's the one being used when I which pip, I get my venv path/bin.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you use a recent version of virtualenv itself, the latest at the time of writing is 1.7.2. Old versions required the use of -E switch, to install into the virtual environment.